# A Movie-type page-transition ? CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, transition

I've been searching for a way to realize a page-blend, but I can only find help for specific animation properties..

What I would like is to have every page-change on my website to get a fade out and and a fade in, like you would between shots in video editing, just a very short and smooth transition. And, ideally it would fade all elements of page X to the background color and fade back into pageY as soon as every element on it is loaded.

Is this a big one? I haven't seen it anywhere but I always wonder if that would be possible - to get a smooth experience without having to see elements load and reposition quickly between page changes?

Comment: Is your website a SPA (single page application)? In order to do transitions *between* page loads, you'll either want a SPA controlling everything and doing the transitions, or to write some Javascript that, upon clicking a link, fades everything out, and on page load fades everything in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Does an SPA make this a lot easier? Even though i want to design a page that looks a lot like a webapp, I'm relatively new to webdesign and would guess the classic linked pages option is the easier setup for me? Ideally I want the code to be easy to apply in different webprojects. How would i get started on the JS road? Are there any frameworks for this ?